# Reproducible kmeans in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am using the document clustering code available [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html). I know that k-means is solving a non-convex problem and hence the results of optimization will differ every time I run it, but is there a way to make the clustering reproducible (maybe by fixing some random seed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the **random_state** parameter of **K-means**. In the following code I use 42:

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1, 
                               verbose=opts.verbose,
                               random_state = 42)
```

You can check the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans).